# Is it necessary to check for isShown() before hiding an SnackBarLayout in android?

Tags: java, android

I am not sure if this is a naive question, I am new to android and couldn't find a answer to this.

I have a SnackbarLayout and I want to hide it so I use the method `SnackbarLayout.hide()`, now is it necessary to check for `SnackbarLayout.isShown()` before hiding it?
Does performing this check have significant advantage over not performing this check?
Another scenario is when the SnackbarLayout is in different fragment and hence not shown on screen but I want to hide it so that if user goes back to the fragment it should be hidden, what can I do in this case? I cannot hide based on whether isShown is true or not, it does not work.

Updating what I found:
For the second part to hide if it is visible in other fragment, I used isSnackbarVisible() instead of isShown(). As the name suggests, the former will be true when it is not seen by user but if its set to visble in for some other fragment)

Comment: You could just try it?

Comment: Well, from what I tried hide() is not really needed because isShown() works without it too. But I don't know if there is any reason that we ned to use it for, because I have seen this practice at many places.

Comment: May I ask which SnackBarLayout you are using? The default support design library does not have a SnackBarLayout class. Only a SnackBar class but that class does not have a hide method.